# OpenCV building issues under Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am programming on Eclipse under Windows 7 and having issues in compiling a small program using OpenCV libraries(2.4.9) 
Here is the list of my path in the GCC++ compiler includes:
"C:\OpenCv2.4.9\opencv\build\include"
"C:\OpenCv2.4.9\opencv\build\include\opencv"
"C:\OpenCv2.4.9\opencv\build\include\opencv2"

I also added these libraries:

- opencv_core249d
- opencv_imgproc249d
- opencv_highgui249d
- opencv_ml249d
- opencv_features2d249d
- opencv_calib3d249d
- opencv_objdetect249d
- opencv_contrib249d
- opencv_legacy249d
- opencv_flann249d

and indicated the following library search path:
"C:\OpenCv2.4.9\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib"
"C:\OpenCv2.4.9\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib"

And what I do not understand, is that this program is compiling

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv ;
int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
   cvNamedWindow( "My Window", 1 );
   IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
   CvFont font;
   double hScale = 1.0;
   double vScale = 1.0;
   int lineWidth = 1;
   cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX | CV_FONT_ITALIC,
          hScale, vScale, 0, lineWidth );
   cvPutText( img, "Hello World!", cvPoint( 200, 400 ), &font,
         cvScalar( 255, 255, 0 ) );
   cvShowImage( "My Window", img );
   cvWaitKey();
   return 0;
 }
```

even though I get no output for it, and the following program:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h >
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
      printf( "No image data \n" );
      return -1;
    }

  namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", image );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

does not compile, underlining in red the opencv functions in the code and showing these messages:

```
D:\SVN\C++ Workspace\OpenCVTest\Debug/../src/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
D:\SVN\C++ Workspace\OpenCVTest\Debug/../src/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
D:\SVN\C++ Workspace\OpenCVTest\Debug/../src/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
D:\SVN\C++ Workspace\OpenCVTest\Debug/../src/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
D:\SVN\C++ Workspace\OpenCVTest\Debug/../src/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
src\main.o: In function `ZN2cv3MatD1Ev':
C:/OpenCv2.4.9/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
src\main.o: In function `ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_':
C:/OpenCv2.4.9/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:298: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
```

Can someone please help me solving this problem? Thanks

Comment: you're using GCC++, but you're linking against library compiled with vc10 (Visual Studio 10).

Comment: Is there any solution to that?